# Automapper-Map to a string

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-3

I tried creating a mapping to a string using the following `CreateMap()`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyComplexType, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(c => c.Name);
```

But when I try to use this mapping, I get the following error:

> Type 'System.String' does not have a default constructor

That makes sense, but I've been reading around and supposedly this should work. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: Do you get any more information on the stack of the exception? This would be tremendously helpful for source code inspection!

Comment: This works fine in a simple example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lA83xE

Comment: What version of AutoMapper are you using?

Comment: I'm using Version 3.1.1

Comment: I am using nuget package   
<package id="AutoMapper" version="4.1.1" targetFramework="net45" /> 
using  
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Brand, string>().ConvertUsing(source => source.Name); 
then     
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Prospect, ProspectDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Brands, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Brands)) 

error when calling  
prospects = db.Prospects.ProjectTo<ProspectDTO>().ToList();

On ProspectDTO the Brands are  
public IEnumerable<string> Brands { get; set; }

Comment: I see stack : 
 System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type) +3792767
   AutoMapper.TypeMap.DestinationConstructorExpression(Expression instanceParameter) +231
   AutoMapper.MappingEngine.CreateMapExpression(ExpressionRequest request, Expression instanceParameter, IDictionary`2 typePairCount) +250

Comment: seems my use case just may not be possible with ProjectTo as per jimmy boggard comments here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/xYRFsIY3Q1w

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using

```
.ProjectTo<>()
```

To project directly from a DBContext collection (EF 6) to my DTO e.g.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
prospects = db.Prospects.Where([my where lambda]).ProjectTo<ProspectDTO>().ToList();
```

With a destination with an `IEnumerable<string>` property coming from a M-M related table i.e.

```
public class ProspectDTO 
{
   public IEnumerable<string> Brands { get; set; }
}
```

and **my solution** was mapping as follows

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Prospect, ProspectDTO>().ForMember(dest => dest.Brands, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Brands.Select(b => b.Name)));
```

N.B. I am using the ProjectTo<> like this to avoid the [common lazy loading select n+1](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/04/03/using-automapper-to-prevent-select-n1-problems/) problem and ensure decent (quick) sql runs against the DB, and I have all the related table data I need. Excellent.

Thanks Jimmy Bogard you rockstar !!!